# Parse Javascript create and manage users from admin

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, admin

I would like to find a way to create and manage created users from an administrator account on javascript.

On creation I would like to override the usual sign in that follows the signup of the user. In other words, when creating a user I don't want Parse to sign in to that user, but to keep the admin session.

Comment: did you find a solution in the meantime?